# Указать url для пагинации в CalendarController

Tags: php, yii2, url

Добрый день! Есть проект на Yii2, в контроллере CalendarController я через action index во view вывожу ListView. Все работает замечательно, но при переключении пагинации, на следующую часть вывода ListView я получаю ссылку вот такого типа:

```
http://site.local/calendar/index?filter=vistavky&page=2
```

А мне нужно

```
http://kultpohod.local/calendar?filter=vistavky&page=2
```

Т.е. index убрать из строки. В Rules прописано сейчас вот так

```
'/calendar/<action:\w+>' => 'calendar/index',
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста как решить эту задачу. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `filter[0]` адэ!

Comment: неправильно скопировал filter=vistavky, хотя сути не меняет

Comment: вы не полностью описали задачу. поэтому однозначно понять что вы хотите нельзя. текущее правило в rules у вас вообще не имеет смысла. это повтор дефолтного механизма парсинга урла. отключить индекс можно через 'showScriptName' => false, ну или если уж правилом то '/calendar' => 'calendar/index', неясно что передается в действие index. или там берется filter через get()? и почему  '/calendar'? вы что используете модуль? если нет - зачем там /

Comment: отключить индекс можно через 'showScriptName' => false - отмена) не про тот индекс подумал)

Comment: calendar -- я использую контроллер с именем CalendarController

Comment: и что? это ясно и так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась просто, нужно было в rules писать

```
'/calendar' => 'calendar/index',
```

а не

```
'/calendar/<action:\w+>' => 'calendar/index',
```

сейчас всё работает и открывается так как нужно, всем спасибо за помощь!